# rails materialize css. Form checkbox not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

Everyone, I am having issues rendering check box with materialize css in rails 5.

#### Here is my form helper

```
<div class="input-field">
  <%= f.check_box :is_furnished %> <br>
  <%= f.label :is_furnished %>
</div>
```

#### inspect source code

```
<div class="input-field">
  <input name="listing[is_furnished]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="listing[is_furnished]" id="listing_is_furnished"> <br>
  <label for="listing_is_furnished">Is furnished</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i finally figured out the issue. I had to wrap the checkbox inside a `<p>` and not a `<div>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way Materialize build its custom checkboxes, adding a `<br>` in between the checkbox and the label will break it. All you need to do is remove `<br>` from your code and it should work.